# Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree

Tags: flutter

I am running into a `globalKey` error after I navigate from `Screen A` to `Screen B` and click a "Cancel" button to go back to `Screen A`.

It seems like the issue is that `Screen B` is either

- A) Not being disposed of correctly
- B) Is not doing something that it otherwise could

And I don't actually know:

- What bad things are happening if I just remove the use of a `globalKey`? (as to get a better understanding of the fundamentals)
- How can I correctly resolve this issue?

StatefulWidget documentation states:[enter link description here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html)

> A StatefulWidget keeps the same State object when moving from one
>   location in the tree to another if its creator used a GlobalKey for
>   its key. Because a widget with a GlobalKey can be used in at most one
>   location in the tree, a widget that uses a GlobalKey has at most one
>   associated element. **The framework takes advantage of this property
>   when moving a widget with a global key from one location in the tree
>   to another by grafting the (unique) subtree associated with that
>   widget** from the old location to the new location (instead of
>   recreating the subtree at the new location). The State objects
>   associated with StatefulWidget are grafted along with the rest of the
>   subtree, which means the State object is reused (instead of being
>   recreated) in the new location. **However, in order to be eligible for
>   grafting, the widget must be inserted into the new location in the
>   same animation frame** in which it was removed from the old location.

Console Error Output:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.
The following GlobalKey was specified multiple times in the widget tree. This will lead to parts of
the widget tree being truncated unexpectedly, because the second time a key is seen, the previous
instance is moved to the new location. The key was:
- [LabeledGlobalKey<FormFieldState<String>>#3c76d]
This was determined by noticing that after the widget with the above global key was moved out of its
previous parent, that previous parent never updated during this frame, meaning that it either did
not update at all or updated before the widget was moved, in either case implying that it still
thinks that it should have a child with that global key.
The specific parent that did not update after having one or more children forcibly removed due to
GlobalKey reparenting is:
- Column(direction: vertical, mainAxisAlignment: start, crossAxisAlignment: center, renderObject:
RenderFlex#7595c relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT)
A GlobalKey can only be specified on one widget at a time in the widget tree.
```

So this part of the error output:

> previous parent never updated during this frame, meaning that it
>   either did not update at all or updated before the widget was moved

makes me think there was some opportunity for my old Stateful widget to do something (either reposition itself or release something as to be disposed correctly.

This seems to be failing in `framework.dart` on `assert(_children.contains(child))`:

```
  @override
  void forgetChild(Element child) {
    assert(_children.contains(child));
    assert(!_forgottenChildren.contains(child));
    _forgottenChildren.add(child);
  }
```

Comment: You probably want to use `popAndPushNamed()` or similar instead of just `pushNamed()` to navigate between pages to avoid pages being added multiple times

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Two things here 1) As luck would have it, I just started using fluro (https://github.com/goposse/fluro) and I don't yet know how `pop` work with that library.. 2) If this error is implying that `Screen A` is still around, is there a way I can just use that instance? (I think the error is all from `Screen A`. Perhaps because there is the original instance of `Screen A` and it's trying to create a new one

Comment: That was my assumption as well. I don't know Fluro though. I think you need top pop the active route to go back to the previous one, or when you push a new route, replace the previous one instead of just adding one of top of the other. `popAndPushNamed()` is how the Flutter router does that, no idea about Fluro.

Comment: @GunterZochbauer yep that was it! I didn't know Widget disposal was tied to 'popping' a route. I guess that makes sense, though. I stopped being lazy and looked at fluro's doc: https://github.com/goposse/fluro/blob/master/lib/src/router.dart#L43-L59 and setting `replace: true` triggered a call to `dispose()` so we are all good. Thanks!

Comment: You could add a short Fluro code example as answer and accept it

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Thanks to Gunter's commments, I determined that this is because the Screens are not being properly disposed.

Flutter's [pushReplacement](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigator.dart#L984-L1010) makes a call to `Route.dispose` which will ultimately dispose the screen.

I am still unsure as to this comes into play:

> widget must be inserted into the new location in the same animation
>   frame

I'm not sure what situation would benefit from such trickery. However, my problem is solved. I just need to make a call to pop or replace.

Here are the available options:

- Use `push` from `A` to `B` and just `Navigator.pop` from `B`
- Use `pushReplacement` from `A` to `B` and from `B` to `A`

I've recently started playing with [Fluro](https://github.com/goposse/fluro) for routing and there are a few more ways to to handle these situations (Note the optional argument [replace](https://github.com/goposse/fluro/blob/master/lib/src/router.dart#L43-L59)):

- Use `router.navigateTo(context, route, replace: false)` from `A` to `B` and `Navigator.pop` from `B`
- Use `router.navigateTo(context, route, replace: true)` from `A` to `B` the same from `B` to `A` (the key is `replace: true`)

Comment: Exactly what i want. Thanks.

Comment: This solves my problem, but I would like to keep the back button functional. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 142):

In my case, it likes a hot reload bug. Just restart debugging works for me.

Comment: Flutter pro-tip: If you get an error, don't assume you actually have error. Restart first.

Comment: I thought It is code issue, really thank you!!!

Comment: Your answer didn't help me.

Comment: Ufffff, after having spent half a day debugging, this is the kind of stuff that makes me chew on my keyboard ...

Answer (score 56):

Remove the static and final type from the key variable so if

```
static final GlobalKey<FormState> _abcKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

change it to

```
GlobalKey<FormState> _abcKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

Comment: This is the answer !!

Comment: right answer!!!

Comment: When I use GlobalKey<FormState> _abcKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();, then I can't use the keyboard anymore, when I am using a smartphone. I just can use the keyboard when I have a static final GlobalKey. Does someone have a solution?

Comment: I must to use static final GlobalKey due to I call some function from another pages like Page.staticGlobalKey.currentState.methodName().
Is there other way to call function from other class without static GlobalKey ?

Answer (score 11):

Make sure that you don't have a `Form` parent and a `Form` child with the same `key`

Answer (score 6):

Best way to solve that, which worked for me:

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
   GlobalKey<FormState> _homeKey = GlobalKey<FormState>(debugLabel: '_homeScreenkey');
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Container(
       key: _homeKey,
     );
   }
}
```

Comment: What is `debugLabel: '_homeScreenkey'`, Kindly explain that what actually you have did here.

Comment: `debugLabel` - it's used to define a individual `label`(a.k.a. name, id) for multiple GlobalKey in app.

Comment: @DumitruBoaghi are you sure it is "a.k.a id"? Documentation states the opposite.
`The label is purely for debugging and not used for comparing the identity of the key.`

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue too. 
I had a four screen bottom tabbed application and a 'logout' method.
However, that logout method was calling a pushReplacementNamed.
This prevented the class that held the global keys (different from the logout function) from calling dispose.

The resolution was to change pushReplacementNamed with popAndPushNamed to get back to my 'login' screen.

Comment: I had a similar setup, but with the GetX package. Get.offAllNamed() was needed to route to and from the auth screen to ensure that all previous routes are disposed.

https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/route_management.md#navigation-with-named-routes

Answer (score 4):

If you have multiple forms with different widgets, you must use separate **GlobalKey** for each form. Like I have two forms, one with Company signup & one with Profile. So, I declared

```
GlobalKey<FormState> signUpCompanyKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
GlobalKey<FormState> signUpProfileKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I wanted to use the `static GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey` but when I used the same widget multiple times it gave this duplicate error.

I wanted to give it a unique string and still use this *scaffold state*.
So I ended up using:

```
static GlobalObjectKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey
```

and in the `initState`:

```
_scaffoldKey = new GlobalObjectKey<ScaffoldState>(id);
```

Edit:
Actually, silly me. I just simply removed the `static` and made it `GlobalKey` again :)

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me, what I did was enclosed the whole view into a navigator using an extension I made

```
Widget addNavigator() => Navigator(
    onGenerateRoute: (_) => MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context2) => Builder(
        builder: (context) => this,
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue on a StatelessWidget class, Converted it to StatefulWidget and error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

please take SingleChildScrollview:

and after if you use the bloc pettern then use strem with broadcast

code is here:

```
        body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/abcd.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Container(child:Form(key: _key,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 100.0, horizontal: 20.0),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(child:Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png', height: 80, width:80,),
                  ),
                  email(),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                  ),
                  password(),
                  row(context),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      ),
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
    );
  }
```

and the bloc pettern code is here:

```
    final _email = StreamController<String>.broadcast();
    final _password = StreamController<String>.broadcast();

    Stream<String> get email => _email.stream.transform(validateEmail);
    Stream<String> get password=> _password.stream.transform(validatepassword);

    Function(String) get changeEmail=> _email.sink.add;
    Function(String) get changePassword => _password.sink.add;

    dispose(){

      _email.close();
      _password.close();
    }

}

final bloc=Bloc();
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error. There was a static bloc object in a class and I removed the static keyword which fixed the error.

Events should be added by using the BlocProvider anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error for using multiple loader in a single page for every API response delay. Applied above all solution but no luck.

finally, used separate Globalkey for every loader calling

```
GlobalKey<State> _loaderDialog = GlobalKey<State>(); 
GlobalKey<State> _loaderDialogForSubmit = GlobalKey<State>();
```

And solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I was using a global key for toast.
Three simple steps:

- late variable
- init globalKey in initState
- dispose globalKey

The simple example of my solution:

```
// STEP 1
late GlobalKey<NavigatorState> productPageNavigatorKey;

class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestScreen({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestScreen> createState() => _ProductCardState();
}

class _ProductCardState extends State<TestScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    
    // STEP 2
    productPageNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    
    // STEP 3
    productPageNavigatorKey.currentState?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      key: productPageNavigatorKey,
      child: Text('Test'),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I also had a similar error.  My answer was that after I updated Flutter some widgets no longer had child or children properties.  In my case it was the CircleAvatar.  The build doesn't error out initially, but when navigating back and forth through the app it will fail.

*Please review all widgets that require a child then review the updated documentation and make sure you're parameters are still correct.