# Failed assertion: line 6075 pos 12: 'child == _child': is not true

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm new to flutter try to display nearst user/vendor to the application. The guy in the tutorial doing it smoothly but I'm getting a lot of errors.I'm writing the exact same codes as he wrote in his tutorial.

- **Failed assertion: line 6075 pos 12: 'child == _child': is not true.**
- **Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.**
- **A RenderShrinkWrappingViewport expected a child of type RenderSliver    but received a child of type RenderFlex.**

Here are my codes.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:paginate_firestore/bloc/pagination_listeners.dart';
import 'package:paginate_firestore/paginate_firestore.dart';
import 'package:phatafut/providers/store_provider.dart';
import 'package:phatafut/services/store_services.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../constants.dart';

class NearestStore extends StatefulWidget {
  static const id = 'nearest-store-screen';
  const NearestStore({key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NearestStoreState createState() => _NearestStoreState();
}

class _NearestStoreState extends State<NearestStore> {
  StoreServices _storeServices = StoreServices();
  PaginateRefreshedChangeListener refreshedChangeListener = PaginateRefreshedChangeListener();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _storeData = Provider.of<StoreProvider>(context);
    _storeData.getUserLocationData(context);

    String getDistance(location){
      var distance = Geolocator.distanceBetween(
        _storeData.userLatitude, _storeData.userLongitude, location.latitude, location.longitude,
      );
      var distanceInKM = distance/1000;
      return distanceInKM.toStringAsFixed(2);
    }

    return Container(
      child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _storeServices.getnearestStore(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>snapShot){
          if(!snapShot.hasData)
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          List shopDistance = [];
          for(int i=0 ; i<=snapShot.data.docs.length-1; i++){
            var distance = Geolocator.distanceBetween(
                _storeData.userLatitude, _storeData.userLongitude,
                snapShot.data.docs[i]['location'].latitude,
                snapShot.data.docs[i]['location'].longitude
            );
            var distanceInKM = distance/1000;
            shopDistance.add(distanceInKM);
          }
          shopDistance.sort();
          if(shopDistance[0]>1){
            return Container();
          }
          return Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              RefreshIndicator(
                child: PaginateFirestore(
                  bottomLoader: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                  ),
                  header: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 8,right: 8,top: 20,),
                        child: Text('All Nearby Stores',
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                            fontSize: 21,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 8,right: 8,top: 20,),
                        child: Text('Find out quality products Nearby You',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 21,
                              color: Colors.blueGrey
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  itemBuilderType: PaginateBuilderType.listView,
                  itemBuilder: (index, context, document)=>
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                    child: Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      child: Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 100,
                            height: 110,
                            child: Card(
                              child: ClipRRect(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                                child: Image.network(document['imageUrl'],fit:BoxFit.cover),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 10,),
                          Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                child: Text(document['shopName'],
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                  maxLines: 2,
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 3,),
                              Text(document['dialog'],
                                style: KShopCardStyle,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 3,),
                              Container(
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-250,
                                child: Text(document['address'],
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                  style: KShopCardStyle,
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 3,),
                              Text('${getDistance(document['location'])}KM',
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                style: KShopCardStyle,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 3,),
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  Icon(Icons.star,
                                    size: 12,
                                    color: Colors.blueGrey,
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(width: 4,),
                                  Text('4.0',
                                    style: KShopCardStyle,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  query: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('vendors')
                      .where('accVerified', isEqualTo: true)
                      .where('isTopPicked',isEqualTo: true)
                      .orderBy('shopName'),
                  listeners: [
                    refreshedChangeListener,
                  ],
                  footer: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30,),
                    child: Container(
                      child: Stack(
                        children: [
                          Center(
                            child: Text('**That\s all folks**',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.blueGrey,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Image.asset('images/city.png'),
                          Positioned(
                            right: 10.0,
                            top: 80,
                            child: Container(
                              width: 100,
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text('Made by : ',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black12,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Text('Adeel',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      letterSpacing: 2,
                                      fontFamily: 'Poppins-Bold',
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                  onRefresh: ()async{
                  refreshedChangeListener.refreshed = true;
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
          );
        },
      ),
      );
  }
}
```

Here is error logs

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#1b72f](state: RawGestureDetectorState#3b342(gestures: <none>, behavior: opaque)):
A RenderShrinkWrappingViewport expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type RenderFlex.

RenderObjects expect specific types of children because they coordinate with their children during layout and paint. For example, a RenderSliver cannot be the child of a RenderBox because a RenderSliver does not understand the RenderBox layout protocol.
The RenderShrinkWrappingViewport that expected a RenderSliver child was created by: ShrinkWrappingViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#8e459] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#1b72f] ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#ad7bb] ← RepaintBoundary ← CustomPaint ← RepaintBoundary ← ⋯
The RenderFlex that did not match the expected child type was created by: Column ← ShrinkWrappingViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#8e459] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#1b72f] ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#ad7bb] ← RepaintBoundary ← CustomPaint ← ⋯
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PaginateFirestore file:///C:/Users/The%20Cubix/StudioProjects/project_phatafut/phatafut/lib/widgets/neareststore.dart:220:24
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      ContainerRenderObjectMixin.debugValidateChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3129:9)
#1      ContainerRenderObjectMixin.debugValidateChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3156:6)
#2      MultiChildRenderObjectElement.insertRenderObjectChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6160:25)
#3      RenderObjectElement.attachRenderObject (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5758:35)
#4      RenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5440:5)
...
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#1b72f](state: RawGestureDetectorState#3b342(gestures: <none>, behavior: opaque)):
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 6075 pos 12: 'child == _child': is not true.


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PaginateFirestore file:///C:/Users/The%20Cubix/StudioProjects/project_phatafut/phatafut/lib/widgets/neareststore.dart:220:24
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.forgetChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6075:12)
#3      Element._retakeInactiveElement (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3563:14)
...     Normal element mounting (10 frames)
#13     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3611:14)
#14     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3360:20)
...
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.

The following GlobalKey was specified multiple times in the widget tree. This will lead to parts of the widget tree being truncated unexpectedly, because the second time a key is seen, the previous instance is moved to the new location. The key was:
- [GlobalKey#8e459]
This was determined by noticing that after the widget with the above global key was moved out of its previous parent, that previous parent never updated during this frame, meaning that it either did not update at all or updated before the widget was moved, in either case implying that it still thinks that it should have a child with that global key.
The specific parent that did not update after having one or more children forcibly removed due to GlobalKey reparenting is:
- Semantics(container: false, properties: SemanticsProperties, label: null, value: null, hint: null, hintOverrides: null, renderObject: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#2d00d NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE DETACHED)
A GlobalKey can only be specified on one widget at a time in the widget tree.
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      BuildOwner.finalizeTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2900:15)
#1      BuildOwner.finalizeTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2925:8)
#2      WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:877:19)
#3      RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:328:5)
#4      SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)
...
====================================================================================================
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49371221/duplicate-globalkey-detected-in-widget-tree

Comment: @gtxtreme thanks for your reply. I'm not using any `globalKey` in my codes. Not even doing navigation.Please see the codes.

Comment: One reason could be if for some reason your widget's constraints are in negative, for example if sizedbox/container height or width is negative.

Comment: @AsfarAli Thanks for your precious reply but I figure it out.

Comment: @AdieRT may i know whats your work around for this? thanks

Answer (score 2):

> A RenderShrinkWrappingViewport expected a child of type RenderSliver
> but received a child of type RenderFlex.

The `header` and `footer` properties are expected to be Slivers (No documentation reference for this but the [example](https://github.com/vedartm/paginate_firestore/blob/6baa94fe7bd6c4cf2f17f26ac3146d11e97a06d7/example/lib/main.dart#L39-L40) and [implementation](https://github.com/vedartm/paginate_firestore/blob/6baa94fe7bd6c4cf2f17f26ac3146d11e97a06d7/lib/paginate_firestore.dart#L177-L198) shows this) so in order to use non-sliver widgets, you can wrap them with [SliverToBoxAdapter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverToBoxAdapter-class.html) which is "a sliver that contains a single box widget."

Update the `header` code to:

```dart
header: SliverToBoxAdapter(
  child: Column(
    ...
  ),
),
```

And update the `footer` code to:

```dart
footer: SliverToBoxAdapter(
  child: Padding(
    ...
  )
),
```

Answer (score 0):

header: SliverToBoxAdapter(
child:Padding(
footer: SliverToBoxAdapter(
child:Padding(

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).