# Tried to build dirty widget in the wrong build scope

Tags: dart, widget, frameworks

What is the main cause of the above error in Flutter? I am simply using the following code, where both the pickers use same code to fetch data from different json.

```
 if (_equipmentSwitch == equipmentType.Implement)
          TractorPicker(mapNotifier: modelNotifier)
        else
          HarvesterPicker(mapNotifier: modelNotifier),
```

HarvesterPicker is working fine. But if I switch to tractorPicker, I get the above error along with this error "Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree" . But I have never used a global key

Comment: it might be a hot reload bug. Just restart debugging may work

Comment: I tried it. Its not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49371221/5197712 did u try these answers ?

Comment: yes I did @ஆனந்த்

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

Since I was using the same `ValueNotifier(modelNotifier)` for both the pickers, this error occured.
Used dispose method to erase the memory of modelNotifier.

```dart
@override
void dispose() {
  modelNotifier.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}
```

This solved my problem.